# Trello always adding 1 hour to my Date

Tags: python, python-3.x, trello

I have a script that sets some Trello cards for me. Everything is working but [card due date](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#put-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-due). Let's say I have the following dates that I got from my SQLite DB:

```
2016-03-30 23:55:00
2016-05-02 23:55:00    
2016-09-30 23:55:00
```

When I run my code, Trello will set them on the cards as:

```
2016-03-31 00:55:00
2016-05-03 00:55:00    
2016-10-01 00:55:00
```

As you can see, due dates on my Trello cards are always 1 hour ahead when they shouldn't. How can I fix that?

Code used: `trello.cards.update_due(card["id"], assignment.due_date)`

Function:

```
def update_due(self, card_id, value):
    resp = requests.put("https://trello.com/1/cards/%s/due" % card_id, params=dict(key=self._apikey, token=self._token), data=dict(value=value))
    resp.raise_for_status()
    return json.loads(resp.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

---

**MORE DETAILS**

```
import dateparser
from datetime import datetime

str_date = 'segunda, 2 Mai 2016, 23:55'  # This is GMT-3 time
tsp = dateparser.parse(str_date, languages=['pt']).timestamp()  # https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest
print(tsp, type(tsp))  # returns: 1462244100.0 <class 'float'>
trello.cards.update_due(card["id"], datetime.fromtimestamp(tsp))  # sets a due time of May 3 at 12:55AM on Trello
```

Comment: Which time zone are you in? Could you give an actual [mcve]?

Comment: I'm on GMT-3, but those dates come from a SQLite DB, exactly as showed in the question.

Comment: And how do you get them out of the database? How do you account for timezones? Are they stored in UTC? Are there relevant Trello settings? Do you pass them as strings, or timestamps, or date time objects? And so on... there is plenty more we'd need to know.

Comment: The dates stored in my DB are always GMT-3. Trello doc only says `Valid Values: A date, or null`, nothing about timezone. Even if I play with my parser's timezone, whatever time I get from it, doesn't matter if PST, EST, UTC, GMT, GMT-3, when I set it on my Trello card it's always 1 hour ahead. I pass them as `str`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [mcve] that actually recreates the issue, rather than just describing it. Code is worth a thousand comments!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried, check the question to see if this is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix, I needed to set `settings={'TIMEZONE': 'America/Sao_Paulo'}` on my `parse()`. Working now!